# Query standard Revit Category with "Fetch Specific Properties" endpoint in Autodesk Forge API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

I wrote an endpoint in my API that queries specific parameters in the client's model using the endpoint described [here](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/metadata/urn-metadata-guid-properties-query-POST/)

In general it works great - my problem lies with how the parameters need to be queried:
the basic ones can be queried directly, while for the others you need to give an exact (with possible wildcards) path:

```
"fields": [
    "objectid",
    "name",
    "externalId",
    "properties.Analytical Properties"
    ...
]
```

the problem specifically is the **Standard Revit Category**, which usually contains a simple string such as '*Revit Wall*'. When querying the Viewer/Model itself, I can find the property without any difficulties, but no matter what I enter into the `"fields"` array, I'm unable to obtain that Category value.

NOTE: selecting an element in the viewer and showing its properties also does not show this parameter, it only shows when querying the model.

[the queried parameter 'Category' in the Revit model - seemingly unattainable via the API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUAGc.png)

edit:

[the same wall when queried via properties endpoint API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQW7a.png)

As you can see, the first few parameters that appear in the first image can't be found in the second one, even when using the JSON-style path withe the corresponding displayCategory *`__category__`*

Comment: In this blog, we described the property structure and how to build the query. Basically, a JSON-path styled key will be composed like 
properties.{category}.{property}   The space is accepted. 
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/advanced-query-model-derivative-api   Are you following the format already? if it does not help, could you share a demo properties for us to diagnose?

Comment: @XiaodongLiang Hi, thank you for your reply, I followed your blog and the JSON-path styled key works perfectly for all regular parameters. I can provide a Revit Model / URN and modelGuid, but it seems that all RevitModels uploaded to forge and queried via the advanced model derivative API don't have the option to return the standard Revit Category Parameter.

I tested the regular _Get Properties_ endpoint on my model as well and was unable to retrieve the parameter in question.


according to the Blog, the JSON-path should be: **'properties.__category__.Category'**
i will update my post

Answer (score 0):

If you were to query the Object Tree of the same `modelGuid`, you'd get the breakdown of the objects like: Model/Category/Family/Type.

Then you'd have to match the `objectid` of your property query with the object tree query. That's the only solution I've found at least (facing a similar issue atm).

[Link to the documentation](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/metadata/urn-metadata-guid-GET/)

Comment: Correct, this has been my go-to workaround as well, I was hoping to use the query approach as it's much faster - but no luck so far.